# Window на весь экран

Tags: c#, wpf

У `Window` указал 2 свойства:
`ShowActivated="False"` и `WindowState.Maximized`

И столкнулся с такой проблемой:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** "Невозможно показать окно, если для `ShowActivated` установлено значение `False`, а для `WindowState` — значение `Maximized`."

А нужно чтобы окно было во весь экран и чтобы окно не забирало фокус на себя при появлении.

**UPD:**
Пока так решил вопрос, правда оно не перекрывает пуск (панель управления):

```
Top = 0;
Left = 0;
Width = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width;
Height = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height;
```

Comment: Ну тогда стартуйте не максимизированным, и «распахивайтесь» после старта — пойдёт?

Comment: @VladD главное чтобы не забирало фокус, если идёт ввод  другое окно, оно не должно прерываться.

Comment: А как (и зачем) вы хотите показать максимизированное окно, не активировав его и "не забирая фокус"? Пользователь будет видеть одно окно, а вводить информацию в другое? Не выглядит хорошей идеей.